# jQuery if input text equals do something

Tags: jquery

If a user types the correct word a function should be called.
Currently i have this jQuery Snippet

```
..
<input type="text" id="code" name="code" placeholder="code">
...
<script>
$(function () {

    var discountCode = 'test4';
    var codeEntered = $("input[name='code']").val();


    $("#subbtn").on("click", function () {

        if (discountCode == codeEntered) {
            alert("RIGHT!");
        } else {
            alert("WRONG!");
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

But i get always "WRONG" even if i type "test4".
What do i wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value of codeEntered after you click.

Here is the corrected code:

```
$(function () {
  $("#subbtn").on("click", function () {
    var codeEntered = $("input[name='code']").val();

    if (discountCode == codeEntered) {
        alert("RIGHT!");
    } else {
        alert("WRONG!");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code `var codeEntered = $("input[name='code']").val();` should be inside the event handler.

```
$("#subbtn").on("click", function () {

    var codeEntered = $("input[name='code']").val();

    if (discountCode == codeEntered) {
        alert("RIGHT!");
    } else {
        alert("WRONG!");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using localecompare

```
discountCode.localeCompare(codeEntered)
```

Comment: Then i get always right no matter what i type .. It should only be right if i type "test4".